# Remove consecutive duplicate characters of even count from the given string

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem where I get the string as input and then delete the duplicate characters of even count.

Input:azxxzyyyddddyzzz

Output: azzz

can you help me with this.

My Attempt is working fine for removing duplicate characters but I'm stuck at how to remove duplicate characters of even count

```
# Utility function to convert string to list 
def toMutable(string): 
    temp = [] 
    for x in string: 
        temp.append(x) 
    return temp 

# Utility function to convert string to list 
def toString(List): 
    return ''.join(List) 

# Function to remove duplicates in a sorted array 
def removeDupsSorted(List): 
    res_ind = 1
    ip_ind = 1

    # In place removal of duplicate characters 
    while ip_ind != len(List): 
        if List[ip_ind] != List[ip_ind-1]: 
            List[res_ind] = List[ip_ind] 
            res_ind += 1
        ip_ind+=1

    # After above step string is efgkorskkorss. 
    # Removing extra kkorss after string 
    string = toString(List[0:res_ind]) 

    return string 

 # Function removes duplicate characters from the string 
 # This function work in-place and fills null characters 
 # in the extra space left 
 def removeDups(string): 
    # Convert string to list 
    List = toMutable(string) 

    # Sort the character list 
    List.sort() 

    # Remove duplicates from sorted 
    return removeDupsSorted(List) 

# Driver program to test the above functions 
string = "geeksforgeeks"
print removeDups(string)
```

Comment: Also there are three y, why are they not in the result?

Comment: Added my attempt

Comment: Also, are you aware that `'xAAAAx'` might result in `'xx'`? Is that OK?

Comment: It should return empty string, because first it should remove 4 A's and then 2 X's

Comment: No, he wants to remove only the consecutive occurrences of every character

Comment: It does not look like given the OP's example :/

Comment: I think that op must be a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt with `itertools.groupby`. I'm not sure if it can be done with better time complexity.

```
from itertools import groupby

def rm_even(s):
    to_join = []
    for _, g in groupby(s):
        chars = list(g)
        if len(chars) % 2:
            to_join.extend(chars)
    if to_join == s:
        return ''.join(to_join)
    return rm_even(to_join)
```

Demo:

```
>>> rm_even('azxxzyyyddddyzzz')
>>> 'azzz'
>>> rm_even('xAAAAx')
>>> ''
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but can we do it without groupby?

Comment: @parvez Why? It's in the standard library.

Comment: But I can't use any library function, it's a constraint

Comment: @parvez you could have mentioned that in the question before people started to work on solutions...

Comment: Time complexity is not an issue, I just need a working solution, sorry, I was n't aware that any other library functions will be required for this, sorry I should have mentioned in the question, anyway thanks for you time and effort @timgeb

Comment: @parvez well you could copy-paste the code for `groupby` into your source code ;) It is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: @parvez my solution does it with no library functions

Comment: @morsecodist what about `enumerate` and `str.join`? ;)

Comment: @timgeb did you remove `_rm_even_rec` method?

Comment: @parvez yes, it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: can you check current code its returning output of `rm_even_rec` response

Comment: @parvez what do you mean? `rm_even('azxxzyyyddddyzzz')` -> `'azzz'` as it is posted.

Comment: @timgeb without that its returning `None`

Comment: @parvez oops! let me fix that.

Comment: @parvez fixed, sorry

Comment: Its failing for this `aaabbbaaabbabddccc` it should return `aaaccc` but returning `bbdd`, test cases are failing now

Comment: @parvez I'm getting `rm_even('aaabbbaaabbabddccc')` -> `'aaaccc'`. That looks correct to me. The subresults are aaabbbaaaabccc -> aaabbbbccc -> aaaccc.

Comment: @timgeb, It is working, It was failing because of some typo, Its working now, Thank you

Comment: Accepted the answer, Thank you very much, You saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Count the letters with `Counter` and remove the ones that have even count:

```
from collections import Counter

word = 'azxxzyyyddddyzzz'
count = Counter(word) # Counter({'z': 5, 'y': 4, 'd': 4, 'x': 2, 'a': 1})
for key, value in count.items():
  if value%2 == 0:
    word = word.replace(key, "")

print(word) # 'azzzzz'
```

Comment: Note that your expected output should be `azzzzz` not `azzz`

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_even_dup(string):    
    spans = []

    for idx, letter in enumerate(string):
        if not len(spans) or spans[-1][0] != letter:
            spans.append((letter, {idx}))
        else:
            spans[-1][1].add(idx)    

    # reverse the spans so we can use them as a stack
    spans = list(reversed(spans))
    visited = []

    while len(spans):
        letter, indexes = spans.pop()
        if len(indexes) % 2 != 0:
            visited.append((letter, indexes))
        else:
            # if we have any previous spans we might need to merge
            if len(visited):
                prev_letter, prev_indexes = visited[-1]
                next_letter, next_indexes = spans[-1]
                # if the previous one and the next one have the same letter, merge them
                if prev_letter == next_letter:
                    # remove the old
                    visited.pop()
                    spans.pop()
                    # add the new to spans to be visited
                    spans.append((letter, prev_indexes | next_indexes))

    to_keep = { idx for _, indexes in visited for idx in indexes }

    return ''.join(letter for idx, letter in enumerate(string) if idx in to_keep)
```

Comment: but It's not correct, final string should be `azzz` not `azzzzz`

Comment: Nvm let me make a change

Comment: There you go, sorry about that. It is messier than the `groupby` solution but no library functions.

Answer (score 0):

I used  Collection because it is easy to delete and we have to convert into the string.

import java.util.*;

public class RemoveEvenCount {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //String a="azxxzyyyddddyzzz";
    String a="xAAAAx";
    ArrayList a2=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        a2.add(a.charAt(i));            
    }           
    a2=removeData(a2);

    System.out.print(a2);           
}

public static ArrayList removeData(ArrayList a2)
{
    if(a2.size()==2)
    {
        if(a2.get(0)==a2.get(1))
                return null;                
        }

    for(int i=0;i<a2.size();i++)
    {
        int count =1;
        for(int j=0;j<a2.size()-1;j++)
        {
            if(a2.get(j)==a2.get(j+1))
            {
                count++;
            }else if(count%2==0)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<count;k++)
                {
                    a2.remove(j-k);
                }
                return removeData(a2);
            }   
            Count=1         
        }       

    }
return a2;
}
```

}